# Any idea why I am getting 'arguments are of the wrong type' error when trying to insert to db with parameterized query?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, parameterized-query

I am attempting to insert some form data into an SQL database with parameterized queries in vbscript in classic asp (I have no experience with asp). I have tried several variations for declaring my parameters but everything is throwing an error.

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another
```

The table in my database won't allow a null for the ApplicationId field and is type int. The TimeStamp column is datetime. All the other fields are varchar(MAX)

Here is the more recent variation of my code please let me know if you can spot any errors etc

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Mode = 3
conn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx;database=db_example;uid=user;pwd=password;"

Dim oCmd 
set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

Dim sSQL 
sSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Application (ApplicationNumber, Expenses, Name, Why) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"

oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
oCmd.ActiveConnection= conn

Dim param1
Set param1 = oCmd.CreateParameter("ApplicationNumber",adInteger,adParamInput)     
param1.value = session.sessionId
oCmd.Parameters.Append param1
```

have tried assigning the value both before and after the Append

```
Dim param2
Set param2 = oCmd.CreateParameter("Expenses",adChar,adParamInput,255) 
param2.value = session("Expenses")
oCmd.Parameters.Append param2

Dim param3
Set param3 = oCmd.CreateParameter("Name",adChar,adParamInput,255) 
param3.value = session("Name")
oCmd.Parameters.Append param3


Dim param4
Set param4 = oCmd.CreateParameter("Why",adChar,adParamInput,255) 
param4.value = session("Why")
oCmd.Parameters.Append param4

Dim oRS
Set oRS = oCmd.Execute()
```

also, the site was hacked so that is why I am rewriting the code with parameterized queries. Here is the original code which worked (but allowed for injection) in case I need to use the recordset or something

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Mode = 3
conn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx;database=db_example;uid=user;pwd=password;"

set rsAddEvent = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
rsAddEvent.open "tbl_Application", conn, 2, 3
rsAddEvent.addnew

rsAddEvent("ApplicationNumber") = session.sessionId
rsAddEvent("TimeStamp") = now()
rsAddEvent("Applicant") = session("Applicant")
rsAddEvent("Email") = session("Email")
rsAddEvent("Pet") = session("Pet")
rsAddEvent("Address") = session("Address")
rsAddEvent("Postal") = session("Postal")
rsAddEvent("HomePhone")  = session("HomePhone")
rsAddEvent("WorkPhone") = session("WorkPhone")
rsAddEvent("Employed") = session("Employed")
rsAddEvent("Employer") = session("Employer")
rsAddEvent("Unemployment") = session("Unemployment")
rsAddEvent("FormerEmployer") = session("FormerEmployer")
rsAddEvent("Dependants") = session("Dependants")
rsAddEvent("Income") = session("Income")
rsAddEvent("OtherIncome") = session("OtherIncome")
rsAddEvent("Funds") = session("Funds")
rsAddEvent("Circumstance") = session("Circumstance")
rsAddEvent("Afford")  = session("Afford")
rsAddEvent("Spent") = session("Spent")
rsAddEvent("Expenses") = session("Expenses") 
rsAddEvent("Name") = session("Name")
rsAddEvent("Email") = session("Email")
rsAddEvent("Why") = session("Why")

rsAddEvent.update
rsAddEvent.movelast
```

Thanks so much for reading through this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to include `adovbs.inc`, and thus the ADO constants such as `adChar` arent recognized.

Try put this at the top of your ASP page:

```
<!--#include virtual="/adovbs.inc"-->
```

If that doesn't work, see this here which explains how to set up the inc file:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513005432/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/faq/Beginner/faq7.shtml

Comment: Thank you, 100000x. You saved me so much time and suffering - Next time you're in Canada I will buy you a beer or 10. :)

Comment: I'll have a Molson Ice, ehh.